# How to block text Message

Tags: android

I want to block this message in string fakeMessage but it doesn't work and i don't know why .............. anyone have any idea to do that

```
  sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String messageText = messageArea.getText().toString();
            String fakeMessage = "hello you win 1000$ with us send your Email pls";

            if(!messageText.equals("")){
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("message", messageText);
                map.put("user", UserDetails.username);

                    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
                        if (map.get(key) == fakeMessage) {

                            Toast.makeText(Chat.this, "This Is A Fake Message and We Can't Send It", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(Chat.this, "Please Don't Try To Send It Again ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {
                            reference1.push().setValue(map);
                            reference2.push().setValue(map);
                            messageArea.setText("");

                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: if (map.get(key) == fakeMessage) ---> if (map.get(key).equals(fakeMessage))

Comment: Not quite sure what you're trying to do, but you definitely should not use `==`to compare strings. Use `String.equals()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change

```
if (map.get(key) == fakeMessage)
```

to:

```
if (map.get(key).equals(fakeMessage))
```

`==` compare object references where as `equals` compare content of String object. Its school boy concept.

Comment: it must work. please debug your code and comparing a long string is always uncertain. you can miss a single space that will result in mismatch

Comment: Toast appear to me but message not blocked that what i mean

Comment: thanks a lot it's work i only add a boolean to check if this case will be true or not and it's work thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If message do not match in case of lower or upper case you compare using equals ignore case.
second you are doing push and setting text two time in for loop you should it only one time, In case of error you can return

```
 sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String messageText = messageArea.getText().toString();
                String fakeMessage = "hello you win 1000$ with us send your Email pls";

                if(!messageText.equals("")){
                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("message", messageText);
                    map.put("user", UserDetails.username);

                        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
                            if (map.get(key).equalsIgnoreCase(fakeMessage)) {

                                Toast.makeText(Chat.this, "This Is A Fake Message and We Can't Send It", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Toast.makeText(Chat.this, "Please Don't Try To Send It Again ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                            } 
                        }
                  reference1.push().setValue(map);
                  reference2.push().setValue(map);
                  messageArea.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks for your help i correct it indeed and it works now 
thanks again